# Swift POST request delivers body to node.js/express application in wrong format

Tags: ios, json, node.js, swift, express

I am trying to send a JSON object from an ios app using Swift. Everything works but the fact that the body in the request  body on the node.js/express backend is in an aca-awkward format where the whole JSON object parsed in Swift is the actual key. So what is being received on the server is:

```
req.body = { '{"email":"email","password":"password"}': '' }
```

I want it to be:

```
{ "email":"email","password":"password" }
```

So I can access the key-values with, for example, `req.body.email`

I am new to http communication between ios and nodejs so maybe this is 
normal but its very annoying.

My ios http post code is :

```
   let url = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:3000/users")

   let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url!)

   request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

   var login_details: [String: AnyObject] = [
     "email" : "\(self.email_field.text)",
     "password" : "\(self.password_field.text)"
   ]

   let valid = NSJSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(login_details)

   var err: NSError?

   request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(login_details, options: nil, error: &err)

   let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
     data, response, error in       
     if error != nil {
       println("error=\(error)")
       return
     }
   }
```

My node router module is:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Node automatically parses the JSON request body to object only if it knows that it is the right content type. You have two possible solutions, use one or the other but not both since they conflict.

1) client side, more correct IMO. Set the right content type. Add this to your Swift code:

```
request.setValue("application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")
```

2) server side. Just parse the body yourself:

```
parsedBody = JSON.parse(body)
// parsedBody will now be an object
```